# Show selected facet values inside node

Tags: search

I'm using facet inside my site and everything works fine.
But I can't display current selected facet inside a node.
I'm explain better.
A user choose from facet menu a birth day and an adress. When he see results and click on a node (I'm using view to display view results and the view has a title with 'link to its entity") what I'd want that he continue to see the facet so he can change his search.
An option is might be to using Ajax and see node type inside the search page. Is it the right way? How can I do it? Thanks in advice

Comment: facetapi is designed to work with SearchAPI afaik and can filter the "current resultset" on a search page. In doing so, facets have a "context" they can work with. On a node view page, there's no context for facets so you can't make it work on a node_view page without hacking it I think. If this is wrong, please someone post the solution!